# What do I have to worry about when making a mobile game for different phones?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, screen-resolution

I want to get into mobile game development but before I get started I want an idea of what the process is like so I can choose the right tools.

Obviously screen resolution is the most obvious, but what other things have to be changed so it will work on multiple phones?

Answer (score 1):

This is an enormous topic. The most basic design is to have a rectangular play area that can be stretched to fit the screen you are using. Whether you keep your original aspect ratio or "match_parent" for both dimensions is up to you.

You've recognized that that won't take full advantage of screens of different resolutions so many courses and tutorials will walk you through learning to design a relative layout that will arrange and size some elements according to the available space and other elements according to how much space the content needs. You'll also eventually provide images of different resolutions that will be used for different screen densities.

I recommend you jump right into game development before understanding this topic fully. There are many intricacies that you'll come to understand as you work with them.

Comment: Is "parent" in "match_parent" referring to the phone's screen size? Thanks

Comment: It refers to a dimension for any view that is set to match the dimension for the view that is above it in the hierarchy of views. But for the context I was talking about above, the answer is yes because the game screen's view would be set to match the full screen size.